# Scala List to Java cannot be cast

Tags: java, scala

I've made two sealed abstract classes in Scala

```scala
sealed abstract class PixelList
case class PCons(hd: (Int, Int), tl: PixelList) extends PixelList
case class PNil() extends PixelList

sealed abstract class DrawingList
case class DCons(hd: (String, PixelList), tl: DrawingList) extends DrawingList
case class DNil() extends DrawingList
```

In my java I get their results in this function:

```java
//Scala getting an array and returning the list
drawEngine.DrawingList drawingList = newDraw.parseCommands(lines);

DrawPixels(drawingList);

private static void DrawPixels(drawEngine.DrawingList lists){
    System.out.println(lists);
    drawEngine.DCons cons = (drawEngine.DCons) lists;
    System.out.println(cons);
    drawEngine.PCons pCons = (drawEngine.PCons) cons.hd()._2;
    System.out.println(pCons);

    while (pCons instanceof drawEngine.PCons) {
        drawEngine.PCons pCon = (drawEngine.PCons) pCons;
        System.out.println(pCon.hd());
        pCons = (drawEngine.PCons) pCon.tl();
    }
}
```

The print output and error is the following:

[image]

How can it be that my `While loop creates this error? -->  drawEngine$PNil cannot be cast to drawEngine$PCons`

Some of the Scala code:
`parseCommands`, takes the array from java, `[drawline(0, 0, 2, 2)]`, and takes it's values, and parse them on to the other functions.

`drawCommands` looks at what case this data fits in, and appends the values to drawObject which is returned.

```scala
def parseCommands(inpuCmd:Array[String]): DrawingList = {
  println("SCALA " + inpuCmd.mkString(" ") );

  // Format input
  val formatCmd = for(row <- inpuCmd) yield {
    val res = row
      .toLowerCase()
      .replaceAll("\\s+","")
      .replace("(", ",")
      .replace(")", "")
      .split(",")
    res
  }
  println(formatCmd(0).mkString(" ") );
  // formatCmd(0)[cmd, arg1,arg....]



  val drawing = drawCommands(formatCmd);
  //val drawing = drawCommands(cmdOnly, argsOnly.toArray);

  //return true;
  return drawing;
}


def drawCommands(inCmd:Array[Array[String]]) : DrawingList = {
  println("drawCommands");

  var drawObject:DrawingList = DNil();
  var tempDraw:DrawingList = drawObject;

  val drawList = for(row <- inCmd) yield {
    tempDraw = drawObject

    if(row(0) != null){
      println("\n row(0) --> " + row(0));
      row(0) match {
        case "bounding-box" => drawObject = Append(tempDraw, ("BLACK", drawRectangle( row(1).toInt, row(2).toInt, row(3).toInt, row(4).toInt )))
        case "drawcircle" =>  drawObject = Append(tempDraw, ("BLACK", drawCircle( row(1).toInt, row(2).toInt, row(3).toInt )))
        case "drawline" =>  drawObject = Append(tempDraw, ("BLACK", drawLine( row(1).toInt, row(2).toInt, row(3).toInt, row(4).toInt )))
        case "drawrectangle" => drawObject = Append(tempDraw, ("BLACK", drawRectangle( row(1).toInt, row(2).toInt, row(3).toInt, row(4).toInt )))
        case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown command: " + row )
      }
    }
  }
  //println(drawObject);

  return drawObject;
}

def Append(dList: DrawingList, item: (String, PixelList)): DrawingList = dList match{
  case DNil() => DCons(item, DNil())
  case DCons(head, tail) => DCons(head, Append(tail, item))
}
```

Comment: This `case DNil() => DCons(item, DNil())` creates an item, on which this `drawEngine.PCons pCons = (drawEngine.PCons) cons.hd()._2;` then fails, because `cons` is `DNil` and `cons.hd._2` is `PNil`. 
It that is not what you expect to be happening, time to power up the debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `pCons` needs to be `PixelList`, for the last element of the list. The error you get is because you are trying to cast `PNil` into `PCons`. This is probably what you are looking for:

```java
private static void DrawPixels(drawEngine.DrawingList lists){
    System.out.println(lists);
    if (lists instanceof drawEngine.DCons) {
        drawEngine.DCons cons = (drawEngine.DCons) lists;
        System.out.println(cons);
        drawEngine.PixelList pCons = cons.hd()._2;
        System.out.println(pCons);

        while (pCons instanceof drawEngine.PCons) {
            drawEngine.PCons pCon = (drawEngine.PCons) pCons;
            System.out.println(pCon.hd());
            pCons = pCon.tl();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("lists are empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made it work tho, but this is a little cleaner :D